# ¿Cómo puedo usar requests con una sesión iniciada?

Tags: python, python-requests

Necesito saber como puedo hacer un request con la sesión ya iniciada.
Por ejemplo en instagram para cambiarnos el nombre de usuario.
El request-URL sería el siguiente: Request URL: https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/
Lo único que se me ocurre serían las cookies.
Ya que en el **FORM DATA** no especifica la contraseña.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Mirate [las sesiones](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) en requests, que mantienen y reenvían automáticamente cookies de peticiones previas.

Comment: @abulafia gracias, puedes iniciar sesión y mandarme el enlace del post? Porque no sé cual es. Y si no es mucha molestia prepararme el código más o menos hecho te lo agradeceria. Gracias.

Comment: @abulafia he hecho esto:
`from requests import post, session, request, cookies

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/'

cookies = {"username":"x", "password":"x"}

data = {'first_name': 'Python Developer',
'email': '90qq09@gmail.com',
'username': 'quique90py',
'phone_number': '',
'biography': "It's python requests",
'Discord': 'quique90#5376',
'external_url':'',
'chaining_enabled': 'on'
}

s = post(url, data=data, cookies=cookies)

print(s.status_code)
print(s.text)`